# C# передача больших файлов(больше 8 кб) по UDP

Tags: c#, udp

Доброе утро, всем!! Есть клиент-серверное приложение на C#.
Сервер:

```
public class UdpFileServer
{
[Serializable]
public class FileDetails
{
    public string FILETYPE = "";
    public long FILESIZE = 0;
}

private static FileDetails fileDet = new FileDetails();

// Поля, связанные с UdpClient
private static IPAddress remoteIPAddress;
private const int remotePort = 5002;
private static UdpClient sender = new UdpClient();
private static IPEndPoint endPoint;

// Filestream object
private static FileStream fs;

[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        // Получаем удаленный IP-адрес и создаем IPEndPoint
        Console.WriteLine("Введите удаленный IP-адрес");
        remoteIPAddress = IPAddress.Parse(Console.ReadLine().ToString());//"127.0.0.1");
        endPoint = new IPEndPoint(remoteIPAddress, remotePort);

        // Получаем путь файла и его размер (должен быть меньше 8kb)
        Console.WriteLine("Введите путь к файлу и его имя");
        fs = new FileStream(@Console.ReadLine().ToString(), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        if (fs.Length > 8192)
        {
            Console.Write("Файл должен весить меньше 8кБ");
            sender.Close();
            fs.Close();
            return;
        }

        // Отправляем информацию о файле
        SendFileInfo();

        // Ждем 2 секунды
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        // Отправляем сам файл
        SendFile();

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
    catch (Exception eR)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(eR.ToString());
    }
}

public static void SendFileInfo()
{

    // Получаем тип и расширение файла
    fileDet.FILETYPE = fs.Name.Substring((int)fs.Name.Length - 3, 3);

    // Получаем длину файла
    fileDet.FILESIZE = fs.Length;

    XmlSerializer fileSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FileDetails));
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

    // Сериализуем объект
    fileSerializer.Serialize(stream, fileDet);

    // Считываем поток в байты
    stream.Position = 0;
    Byte[] bytes = new Byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Read(bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(stream.Length));

    Console.WriteLine("Отправка деталей файла...");

    // Отправляем информацию о файле
    sender.Send(bytes, bytes.Length, endPoint);
    stream.Close();

}

private static void SendFile()
{
    // Создаем файловый поток и переводим его в байты
    Byte[] bytes = new Byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

    Console.WriteLine("Отправка файла размером " + fs.Length + " байт");
    try
    {
        // Отправляем файл
        sender.Send(bytes, bytes.Length, endPoint);
    }
    catch (Exception eR)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(eR.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        // Закрываем соединение и очищаем поток
        fs.Close();
        sender.Close();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Файл успешно отправлен.");
    Console.Read();
}

  }
```

Клиент:

```
public class UdpFileClient
{
// Детали файла
[Serializable]
public class FileDetails
{
    public string FILETYPE = "";
    public long FILESIZE = 0;
}

private static FileDetails fileDet;

// Поля, связанные с UdpClient
private static int localPort = 5002;
private static UdpClient receivingUdpClient = new UdpClient(localPort);
private static IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = null;

private static FileStream fs;
private static Byte[] receiveBytes = new Byte[0];


[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Получаем информацию о файле
    GetFileDetails();

    // Получаем файл
    ReceiveFile();
}


private static void GetFileDetails()
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-----------*******Ожидание информации о файле*******-----------");

        // Получаем информацию о файле
        receiveBytes = receivingUdpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
        Console.WriteLine("----Информация о файле получена!");

        XmlSerializer fileSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FileDetails));
        MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();

        // Считываем информацию о файле
        stream1.Write(receiveBytes, 0, receiveBytes.Length);
        stream1.Position = 0;

        // Вызываем метод Deserialize
        fileDet = (FileDetails)fileSerializer.Deserialize(stream1);
        Console.WriteLine("Получен файл типа ." + fileDet.FILETYPE +
            " имеющий размер " + fileDet.FILESIZE.ToString() + " байт");
    }
    catch (Exception eR)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(eR.ToString());
    }
}


public static void ReceiveFile()
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-----------*******Ожидайте получение файла*******-----------");

        // Получаем файл
        receiveBytes = receivingUdpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);

        // Преобразуем и отображаем данные
        Console.WriteLine("----Файл получен...Сохраняем...");

        // Создаем временный файл с полученным расширением
        fs = new FileStream("temp." + fileDet.FILETYPE, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        fs.Write(receiveBytes, 0, receiveBytes.Length);

        Console.WriteLine("----Файл сохранен...");

        Console.WriteLine("-------Открытие файла------");

        // Открываем файл связанной с ним программой
        Process.Start(fs.Name);
    }
    catch (Exception eR)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(eR.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        fs.Close();
        receivingUdpClient.Close();
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

}

Как сделать так, чтобы можно было передавать файлы больше 8кб??Пожалуйста помогите

Comment: Передавать порциями по 8 Кб? Но лучше все же TCP для этой цели.

Comment: получается да!!

Comment: Можно закрывать вопрос?)

Comment: если хочется передавать файлы по udp, то желательно брать размер пакета меньше udp. Для локальной сети это где то 1500 байт, для всего интернета в  районе 500-600 байт. Иначе пакеты будут дробится и  вероятность того, что весь пакет добежит  - маленькая.

Comment: Сказали на UDP, делать..

Comment: Протокол UDP так-то поддерживает передачу датаграмм размером в 8 КБ (максимальный размер датаграммы что-то около 65 КБ). Если в вашей сети они не доходят, это проблема сети, а не протокола.

Comment: Пошлите их сразу же. Или пилите TCP поверх UDP. Голый UDP не гарантирует доставку и порядок.

Comment: А да, есть еще одно ограничение, размер буфера в Winsock. Через UdpClient.Client.ReceiveBufferSize / SendBufferSize можно увеличить. Но это плохая идея, нужно дробить файл на маленькие части и передавать с указанием порядкового номера, потом на клиенте склеивать.